# Identifying iPad/iPhone/iPod models xcode device -> known name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I was looking around and could not find all possible models, usually up to iPad 3 Generation and iPhone 5. What are the iPhone 5s,c and iPad air device names?

Comment: Am I missing the question?

Comment: It is not a question, just for informational purposes for people who are interested in, because I couldn't find for latest devices so I researched, wrote and shared with people.

Comment: While this is good information, we're a question and answer site, so your question needs to actually be a question. Fortunately, you can answer your own question, so you should post a question along the lines of "what do all the device codes mean" and post this as an answer.

Comment: Please phrase your answer in the form of a question. — Alex Trebek

Comment: @Kevin I rewrote it and answered it.

Answer (score 1):

So I've spent some time researching and putting those together. For all developers that are looking to identify models of all apple touch devices, here is a list which includes iPhone 5s,c, iPod touch 5 Gen iPad Air and iPad mini (latest model):

```
#import "sys/sysctl.h"

        size_t size;
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
        char *machine = malloc(size);
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
        NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
        free(machine);    
        NSString *deviceModelDetailed;
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 1G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 3G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 3GS";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 4";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 4 (GSM Rev A)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 4S";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5 (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5c (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPhone 5s (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPod Touch 1G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPod Touch 2G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPod Touch 3G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"]){
           deviceModelDetailed = @"iPod Touch 4G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPod Touch 5G";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 1";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (GSM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 2 Wi-Fi (Rev A)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad mini";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad (4th generation)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM)";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad Air";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad mini with Retina display";
        }
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"]){
            deviceModelDetailed = @"iPad mini with Retina display Wi-Fi + Cellular";
        }
```